# Why doesn't $(document).data() work within $(document).ready()?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which successfully stores `urltostore.php` as `mysite.option` which I can then use as a global variable.

```
<script>
$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");
</script>

<script>
alert($(document).data('mysite.option'));
</script>
```

If I put the `$(document).data` function within a `$(document).ready` function, it stops working:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");
});
</script>

<script>
alert($(document).data('mysite.option'));
</script>
```

Ultimately, I'd like to put the `$(document).data` function within an if condition:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if (leveldeterminant == 0{
$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");
}
});
</script>

<script>
alert($(document).data('mysite.option'));
</script>
```

Comment: Alert block everything(page rendering too), that's why you are getting undefined, because page not rendered and `$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");` is not executed. put alert also inside document.ready

Comment: Do you know what `$(document).ready()` does?

Comment: My main question is: how can I make `$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");` depend on an `if condition`? Without `$(document).ready`, the `if (leveldeterminant == 0{` condition isn't read

Comment: I modified my post to make it more in line with what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried to simplify to an `alert` function but I think that's distracting from the main issue I'm having

Comment: you have to show full code  like what is `mysite.option` ? how you are creating it? please share that in your question

Comment: That is the full code. `mysite.option` is just a random word that I chose to have the value `urltostore.php` assigned to it. That first bit of code successfully prints `urltostore.php` without involving any other code (aside from the Jquery plugin)

Comment: I just redid the code in my server using the word `blah` instead of `mysite.option` and it still worked as long as I didn't include `$(document).ready` or the if condition....which is what I'm trying to figure out how to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because of how the JavaScript event loop works and the behavior of `$(document).ready()`. When you don't put `$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");` in the `$(document).ready()`, it gets called immediately and it is available when you need it.

However, when stick it inside `$(document).ready()`, the anonymous function that's wrapped around it is scheduled to execute after the DOM is finished loading, so it doesn't actually execute right away. It waits for the DOM ready event, which is after you call `alert($(document).data('mysite.option'));`.

If you stuck `alert($(document).data('mysite.option'));` in a `$(document).ready()`, I would expect it to work as you expect.

As for adding a conditional, it should work as normal, whether or not you stick it in a `$(document).ready()`.

This should work if `leveldeterminant` equals 0:

```
if (leveldeterminant == 0) {
    $(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea but the wrong explanation; the event loop and stack doesn't have anything to do with it. `$(document).ready()` waits for the DOM to finish loading, not the event loop to finish.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! How can I make the setting of 
`$(document).data('mysite.option', "urltostore.php");` depend on a condition then? Without `$(document).ready`, the `if (leveldeterminant == 0{` condition isn't read

Comment: I modified my post to make it more in line with what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried to simplify to an alert function but I think that's distracting from the main issue I'm having

Comment: @EmptyArsenal If you could take a look at how the PHP that I added to my original post would fit into this, I would really appreciate it! The alert isn't actually in my code - I just tried to use it in place of the PHP to simplify the issue. I would be able to put the php inside of the same `$(document).ready` function as I could with the `alert`

Comment: I accepted your answer because it did answer the question that I asked, but unfortunately my issue still isn't solved. (Please see edited original post.)

Comment: @Snoops A good SO question is very specific and focuses on one issue. In your case, you have three: 1. Why behavior appears different in `.ready()`, 2. Why your conditional isn't working, and 3. A question regarding PHP. The more you throw in, the more the answer strays and the less useful it is for others. #1 is a good question, #2 is a bit of a stretch, and #3 should be a different question. If you have a question regarding PHP, I'd open a new question with more details and focus on your PHP issue. Good luck!

Comment: @EmptyArsenal Makes sense! I did resubmit the post with a more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001447/having-difficulty-using-document-data-within-an-if-condition/46001506?noredirect=1#comment78963643_46001506