# Having difficulty using $(document).data() within an if condition

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which successfully stores `value` as `name` which I can then use as a global variable within php. This is the full code (aside from tags & jquery link):

```
<script>
$(document).data('name', "value");
</script>

<?php $Phpvar = "<script>document.writeln($(document).data('name'))‌​;</script>"; 
print_r($Phpvar); ?> //Prints "value"
```

However, this stops working if I put the `$(document).data` function within an if condition:

```
<head>
<script>
if ($("div").hasClass("blah")){
$(document).data('name', "value");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "blah"></div>

<?php $Phpvar = "<script>document.writeln($(document).data('name'))‌​;</script>"; 
print_r($Phpvar); ?> //Prints "undefined"
</body>
```

I tried `$(document).ready` but that still doesn't work. (`another variable` is definitely equal to 0):

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($("div").hasClass("blah")){
$(document).data('name', "value");
}
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "blah"></div>

<?php $Phpvar = "<script>document.writeln($(document).data('name'))‌​;</script>"; 
print_r($Phpvar); ?> //Prints "undefined"
<body>
```

How can I add a condition to my `$(document).data('name', "value");` while maintaining the capability to use `document.writeln($(document).data('name'))‌​;` in my php?

Comment: Is the missing closing parenthesis a real error in your code, or just here `if (anothervariable == 0{`

Comment: @Jamiec Good question - just made a typo here. The closing parenthesis is in my actual code. will edit OP

Comment: Consider when your code runs - if you use doc.ready, your `if` statement will run sometime after your additional script.

Comment: Where/When is `anothervariable` defined/set?

Comment: @freedomn-m It definitely wasn't the variable; I modified the original post because I felt like that was detracting from the main issue

Comment: Ok, same question - where/when is `<div>` defined?  From the edit, it looks like it's *after* the `script` tag, so will never have that class when the script runs.   Easiest debug option is to add an alert before `$(document).data('name', "value");` , ie `alert("has blah")`

Comment: @freedomn-m The script tag is in the head and the `div` is in the `body`. The alert works in all three conditions so that if condition is absolutely being met.

Comment: The issue is the condition within the `if` - whether this is a variable or some jquery to query a parameter.  If that condition is not being tested correctly *at the time it runs* then your if will fail, which is exactly what you are reporting.

Comment: @freedomn-m But I don't understand why     `$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("div").hasClass("blah")){
    alert("has class");
    }
    });` works and `$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("div").hasClass("blah")){
    $(document).data('name', "value");
    }
    });` doesn't

Comment: Because when you use `document.ready()` the code inside the ready function runs last.  When you do not use it, it runs first.  This is not the issue - the issue is `<?php $Phpvar = "<script>document.writeln($(document).data('name'))‌​;</script>"; 
print_r($Phpvar); ?>` which is running `document.writeln` immediately at the point of the script.  ie (when using doc.ready) *before* your code inside the doc.ready has run.   When not using doc.ready, your `if` is not working as the `div` does not yet exist.    Try putting your `if` code (without doc ready) directly before the php script.

Comment: All of that makes sense; I appreciate your parsing that out. When I put the if code right before the php script it prints `}` Code: `<script>if ($("div").hasClass("SimplifyingFractionsQuestion")){ <?php $UrlReplace = "<script>document.writeln($(document).data('blah'));</script‌​>"; print_r($UrlReplace); ?> } </script>`

Comment: I also tried: `<script>if ($("div").hasClass("SimplifyingFractionsQuestion")){ <?php $UrlReplace = "?>document.writeln($(document).data('blah'));<?php"; print_r($UrlReplace); ?> } </script>` but that returned nothing

Answer (score 0):

The obvious conclusion is that leveldeterminant does not in fact equal 0. Add a console.log(leveldeterminant) before your if statement and check what value it holds

Comment: Thanks for the input! That was just a typo in this post. The issue remains, unfortunately

Comment: Could you try what I suggested? Substitute the altered variable name of course

Comment: Yep, but in the meantime, I did a similar assessment: I substituted `$(".img-box").hide();` in place of `  $(document).data('name', "value");` as follows and the image hid:: `$(document).ready(function(){
if (anothervariable == 0){
$(".img-box").hide();
}
});`

Comment: I modified the original post so the variable isn't involved because I felt like that was distracting from the main issue

Answer (score -1):

You should close your if block

```
<body>
    <div class="blah"></div>
    <script>
      if ($('div.blah').length) $(document).data('name', 'value');
    </script>
    <?php $Phpvar = "<script>document.writeln($(document).data('name'))‌​;</script>"; 
    print_r($Phpvar); ?>
<body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! That was just a typo in this post. The issue remains, unfortunately

Comment: Sorry for late. Was out of touch - I have updated my answer, but haven't tested it. Can you check if you're still facing the issue